# MySQL's instructions for upgrading 5.7 to 7 with Yum assume that I have a mysql-community.repo file but I only have Mysql57.repo. What should I do?

Tags: mysql, centos, centos7, yum

I'm trying to do an "upgrade in place" of MySQL 5.7 to MySQL 8 on CentOS 7.

I am following MySQL's instructions here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-repo-excerpt/8.0/en/updating-yum-repo.html

The first step is called "Selecting a Target Series". They send me to the instructions here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-repo-excerpt/8.0/en/linux-installation-yum-repo.html#yum-repo-select-series in which they reference the following file: `/etc/yum.repos.d/mysql-community.repo`. My system does not have this file, but it does have `/etc/yum.repos.d/Mysql57.repo`

Here are the contents of Mysql57.repo:

```
[Mysql-connectors-community]
name=MySQL Connectors Community
baseurl=https://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-connectors-community/el/7/$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://repo.mysql.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-MySQL-2022
       https://repo.mysql.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql
[Mysql-tools-community]
name=MySQL Tools Community
baseurl=https://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-tools-community/el/7/$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://repo.mysql.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-MySQL-2022
       https://repo.mysql.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql
[Mysql57-community]
name=MySQL 5.7 Community Server
baseurl=https://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-5.7-community/el/7/$basearch/
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://repo.mysql.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-MySQL-2022
       https://repo.mysql.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql
[Mysql-tools-preview]
name=MySQL Tools Preview
baseurl=https://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-tools-preview/el/7/$basearch/
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://repo.mysql.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-MySQL-2022
       https://repo.mysql.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql
```

**How do I "select a target series" so that I can run the following command?**

`sudo yum update mysql-server`

Do I create a new file called `/etc/yum.repos.d/mysql-community.repo`? If so, what should its file contents be? Do I remove the file `/etc/yum.repos.d/Mysql57.repo`?

I have spent hours Googling, but my knowledge of package managers and Linux must be too weak.

Comment: It is now the case that in-place upgrades are not possible in the MySQL 8 era. You basically have to dump all your data and import it to the next version on every update. Cf. https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=109075

Comment: Read the bug. There can be zero dates in some hidden system tables. The person who reported that bug had to install a debug version of MySQL to get access to the hidden tables, before they could upgrade. IMHO, MySQL is regressing, and their verification team closes reports of such regressions as "works as designed."

Comment: @BillKarwin What do you suggest I do in my situation? I certainly have websites that have nasty zero dates (WordPress sites, etc.)

Comment: I don't know. I think MySQL is at an inflection point. The 8.0 version is becoming less and less stable, and I don't know what its future is. If they don't fix it and keep it stable, I won't use MySQL again. I'll be using PostgreSQL. I understand why this is a problem for WordPress users, because WordPress officially supports only MySQL by default. But there are [solutions emerging for that](https://hevodata.com/learn/wordpress-postgresql/).

Comment: In the meantime, I guess either stay on the last MySQL 5.7 release indefinitely (even though it's EOL), or else get use to painful upgrades. Some may consider MariaDB an option, but I will never use MariaDB.